# Why Expressions are not dynamically updated in angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here in this code i have used two dynamic variables `fbid` and `fburl`. `fburl` is a expression using `fbid`.

`$scope.fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+$scope.fbid+"/picture?type=normal";`

Here is my code.

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module("testApp", [])
  .controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.fbid = "bennadel";
    $scope.fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+$scope.fbid+"/picture?type=normal";
    console.log($scope.fburl);
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    FacebookID<input type="text" ng-model="fbid" >
    <img ng-src= "{{fburl}}"/>
   <div>{{fburl}}</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Now my question is when I am updating the `fbid` why `fburl` is not updating automatically ?

Comment: Angular not watch for setted values, you must say it.Using $scope.$watch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the value can't update after the fact, you need to add a watcher on the variable fbid.

[AngularJS docuemntation for $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module("testApp", [])
  .controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.fbid = "bennadel";
    $scope.fburl = "";
    $scope.$watch('fbid ', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+newValue+"/picture?type=normal";
        console.log($scope.fburl);
    });
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    FacebookID<input type="text" ng-model="fbid" >
    <img ng-src= "{{fburl}}"/>
   <div ng-bind="fburl"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution - cleaner way.

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module("testApp", [])
  .controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.fbid = "bennadel";
$scope.fbFn = function() {
                return "https://graph.facebook.com/"+$scope.fbid+"/picture?type=normal";
            };
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    FacebookID<input type="text" ng-model="fbid" >
<img ng-src= "{{fbFn()}}"/>
    <div >{{fbFn()}}</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Happy Helping!

Comment: When you assigned a function to `fbFn` its work, but why its not working when I directly assign a the expression value to the variable?

Comment: when there is change in **$scope.anyPropery** ($scope.fbid in this case) **$digest** is run which causes all $scope-associated functions also run, that's why 'fbFn' is working here. I like this approach compared to setting $watch. You can understand more about [$diget cycle working](http://www.slideshare.net/straker503/angularjs-performance)